# Attempt to apply non-function in a sequence

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a sequence with these conditions:

```
y<-seq(from=a-2(b-a), to=a+2(b-a), by=4(b-a)/99, length.out=100)
```

Given:

```
sample=rnorm(50, mean=0, sd=1)
sample_min=min(sample)
a<-sample_min
sample_max=max(sample)
b<-sample_max
```

And I get the error "attempt to apply non-function in a sequence." How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `2(b-a)` in the console:

```
2(b-a)
# Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

R doesn't know you want multiplication, so it thinks `2(b-a)` is a function `2()` with the argument `b-a`.  You need to specify multiplication with the arithmetic operator `*`.  So `a-2(b-a)` should be `a-2*(b-a)`, and the same for the `to` and `by` arguments.

After you do that, you will need to remove one of either the `to` or `length.out` arguments because that will also create an error. `to` and `length.out` cannot be used together.  The final product will be

```
seq(from = a - 2 * (b - a), to = a + 2 * (b - a), by = 4 * (b - a) / 99) 
## or
seq(from = a - 2 * (b - a), by = 4 * (b - a) / 99, length.out = 100)
```

See `help(seq)` for more.